# Send JMS message after transaction commits

Tags: spring, hibernate, jms

I have a application (APP1) where I'm working with hibernate and JMS. I have a method annotated with @Transactional. This method inserts data in a database and later sends data to a MQ.
I'm encountering a problem where the consumer application (APP2) gets the message from the MQ and calls APP1, but as APP1 is not finished commiting data the database, it returns an error saying that the data could not be found.

Is there a way where I can commit the database inserts before sending the JMS message?

```
@Transactional
public void create(Data data){
     doSomeValidation();
     anotherClass.insertInDB(data.name, data.email);

     thirdClass.sendDataToMQ(data.id);
}
```

```
@Transactional
public void insertInDB(String name, String email) {
     Entity entity = new Entity();
     entity.setName(name);
     entity.setEmail(email);
     repository.saveAndFlush(entity)
}
```

```
@Transactional
public void sendDataToMQ(int id) {
     Entity entity = repository.findById(id);
     jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
     jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(someDestination, new Message(entity)message -> {
                return message;
            });
    doSomeUpdateInDB(int id);
}
```

Comment: Use an `@TransactionalEventListener` for that which will fire after the commit.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried replacing Transactional with TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT) on the sendDataToMQ method but that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: You need to send an event which willbe processed by that listener... I suggest a read of the spring framework guide relating to this.

Comment: It stands to reason that if you're using the proper XA resources then inserting data into the database and sending the JMS message should be performed atomically so that the data is in the database by the time the consumer receives the JMS message. That's one of the main benefits of transactions - atomicity.

Comment: @JustinBertram agreed, thats why I'm confused on why it is not working as I intend to :-)

Comment: My guess is that you have something misconfigured in your application. You should probably change your question to ask how to perform an XA transaction with Spring rather than asking how to send a JMS message after a transaction commits. An XA transaction requires a transaction manager and XA resources for both JDBC and JMS which almost certainly requires more than just `@Transactional`, but then again I'm no Spring expert.